# Integral boundaries in MatLab, reaching the limit of calculating error intervals

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I want to solve a double integral with infinite boundaries. After computing a long while MatLab tells me that I "Reached the limit on the maximum number of intervals in use. Approximate bound on error is 2.1e+07.The integral may not exist, or it may be difficult to approximate numerically to the requested accuracy." My code is

```
    %%%%%%%%%
close all;
clear all;
format long;
e=1.60217653*10^(-19);
h=6.6260693*10^(-34);
hbar=h/(2*pi);
m=9.1093826*10^(-31);
T=293.15;
k_B=1.38065*10^(-23);
rho=1.5*10^(-2);              
delta=7.4*10^(-6);            
L=0.01;                 
U_b=1665;          
v=sqrt((2*e*U_b)/m);   
c=299792458;            
lambda=h/(sqrt(2*m*e*U_b));     
epsilon_0=8.854187817*10^(-12); 
omega_P=7.88*10^(12);              
gamma_0=8.25*10^(11);     
t=L./v;                     

func_epsilon=@(w) 1-((omega_P.^2)./(w.*(w+1i*gamma_0)));

func_r_P=@(w,k_x,k_y) (func_epsilon(w).*sqrt((w.^2)./(c^2)-sqrt(k_x.^2+k_y.^2).^2)-sqrt((w.^2.*func_epsilon(w))./(c^2)-sqrt(k_x.^2+k_y.^2).^2))./(func_epsilon(w).*sqrt((w.^2)./(c^2)-sqrt(k_x.^2+k_y.^2).^2)+sqrt((w.^2.*func_epsilon(w))./(c^2)-sqrt(k_x.^2+k_y.^2).^2));
func_r_S=@(w,k_x,k_y) (sqrt((w.^2)./(c^2)-sqrt(k_x.^2+k_y.^2).^2)-sqrt((w.^2.*func_epsilon(w))./(c^2)-sqrt(k_x.^2+k_y.^2).^2))./(sqrt((w.^2)./(c^2)-sqrt(k_x.^2+k_y.^2).^2)+sqrt((w.^2.*func_epsilon(w))./(c^2)-sqrt(k_x.^2+k_y.^2).^2));


z = (0:10^(-9):30*10^(-6));

f_1=@(k_x,k_y) (1-cos(k_x.*delta)).*(2*k_B*T)./(hbar.*abs(k_y.*v));
f_3=@(k_x,k_y) imag(func_r_P(abs(k_y.*v),k_x,k_y).*(1-(v.^2.*k_y.^2)./(c.^2.*(k_x.^2+k_y.^2)))+func_r_S(abs(k_y.*v),k_x,k_y).*(v.^2./c.^2).*(k_x.^2)./(k_x.^2+k_y.^2));
for ii=1:length(z)
f_2=@(k_x,k_y) (exp(-2.*sqrt(k_x.^2+k_y.^2).*z(ii).*sqrt(1-(v.^2.*k_y.^2)./(c.^2.*(k_x.^2+k_y.^2)))))./(2.*sqrt(k_x.^2+k_y.^2).*sqrt(1-(v.^2.*k_y.^2)./(c.^2.*(k_x.^2+k_y.^2))));
func_u=@(k_x,k_y) f_1(k_x,k_y).*f_2(k_x,k_y).*f_3(k_x,k_y);

gamma=-((t.*e^2)./(epsilon_0*hbar*4*pi*pi)).*integral2(@(k_x,k_y)func_u(k_x,k_y),-inf,inf,-inf,inf);                

gamma_save(ii)=gamma;

end

y = exp(gamma_save);
plot(z,y); 
ylim([0 1.1]);
title('test');
xlabel('z [m]');
ylabel('K'); 

%matlab2tikz('standalone',true,'externalData',true);
```

What I'm doing wrong? Interestingly, my result strongly varies for boundaries of e.g. -1e9,1e9 or for -1e8,1e8. However, for finite (high) boundaries the result stays false. Is the step size for the variable z decisive? Is MatLab suited for this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered that "The integral may not exist, or it may be difficult to approximate numerically to the requested accuracy" ?

Comment: Note that your function has 40 orders of magnitude of difference in its parameters. This will likely be very difficult to work with with standard floating point arithmetic. Perhaps VPA will help, or symbolic maths.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I see the difficulties with the parameters but I just want to recalculate an existing theory (and plot). For the integral boundaries of 1e5 etc. I receive a qualitative good result but not for 1e4 or 1e7. This is what confuses me. VPA is new to me, maybe I try this.

Comment: Numerical instability its not linear, well, because its instable. If the problem is that, then doesn't matter that it works some times, that doesnt make it faultproof

Comment: To motivate answers, can you link an image file of your formulas? I'm honestly not going to read these integrands in matlab code. Also please comment your code if you are using it as a part of your question. 
Aside, are you trying to do feyman path integral or some spring system?